# validation expression in asp.net

Tags: asp.net, validation

I am trying to create a validation expression for my regular expression validator control.  I am having trouble understanding how to add things to the validation expression.  I need it to accept any input (numbers, characters, any special characters) and limit the input to 200.   I have this so far:

```
 <asp:RegularExpressionValidator ID="commentRegularExpressionValidator" runat="server"   ErrorMessage="Comment box exceeds 200 characters."
                  ControlToValidate="TextBoxComments"
                  ValidationExpression="^[a-zA-Z''-'\s\d ^!@#$%^&*()_+=-]{0,200}$"
                  Text="*"
                  CssClass="errorMessage"
                  SetFocusOnError="true"
                  Display="Dynamic"
                  ValidationGroup="infoGroup"></asp:RegularExpressionValidator>
```

When I try to add more special characters to the expression, I start getting errors.  Can somebody help clarify the format/structure of adding special characters to this validation expression.  Thank you

Comment: @user3255899..Why you need RegularExpression validator only..?

Answer (score 1):

If you need only to accept any input (numbers, characters, any special characters) and limit the input to 200 then Set only property of Textbox like --> `MaxLength="200"` 
Or if you want to show message then use javascript or Jquery like below function on `Keydown` event of textbox-->

```
    function CountCharacters() {
                var maxSize = 200;
                if (document.getElementById('<%= txt_handlinginfo.ClientID %>').value != '') {                 
                    var len = document.getElementById('<%= TextBoxComments.ClientID %>').value.length;
                    if (len > maxSize) {
                       alert('error message');
                       return false;
                        }
                    }                    
                }
```

Comment: Im required to use validators though.....so if they enter more then 200, it will create an error message in the validation summary on the page

Comment: Than use javascript or jquery in place of asp.net regular expression.. they are light and easy to use..

Answer (score 0):

You can use `.{1,200}` regular expression.

`. dot` character means any character

`{1,200}` means match 1 or more character upto max 200 characters.

```
<asp:RegularExpressionValidator ID="commentRegularExpressionValidator" runat="server"      
                  ErrorMessage="Comment box exceeds 200 characters."
                  ControlToValidate="TextBoxComments"
                  ValidationExpression=".{1,200}"
                  Text="*"
                  CssClass="errorMessage"
                  SetFocusOnError="true"
                  Display="Dynamic"
                  ValidationGroup="infoGroup">
</asp:RegularExpressionValidator>
```